# Some Reverse GeoCode queries return null

Tags: here-api

We are attempting to retrieve district information for a number of locations.
However the Here API returns no values.
These locations are in the state of Arunachal Pradesh and Jammu & Kashmir in India.

I tested with a number of latitude/longitudes for these states. None of them return any data.

```
https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=28.2180,94.7278&mode=retrieveAreas&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Response:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "MetaInfo": {
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-05T15:11:46.711+0000"
        },
        "View": []
    }
}
```

Even when I choose a location from Google Maps and use that in the API call, it still returns null.

```
https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=27.083227, 93.605954&mode=retrieveAreas&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Response:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "MetaInfo": {
            "Timestamp": "2020-08-05T15:11:46.711+0000"
        },
        "View": []
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice you are using the older version of the API. Can you try the latest version documented here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-reverse-geocode-brief.html

Answer (score 1):

The Geocoding and Search API v7 is recommended.

```
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=28.2180%2C94.7278&lang=en-US

{
"items": [
    {
        "title": "Jomlo Mobuk, Arunachal Pradesh, India",
        "id": "here:cm:namedplace:22803761",
        "resultType": "locality",
        "localityType": "city",
        "address": {
            "label": "Jomlo Mobuk, Arunachal Pradesh, India",
            "countryCode": "IND",
            "countryName": "India",
            "state": "Arunachal Pradesh",
            "county": "Siang",
            "city": "Jomlo Mobuk",
            "postalCode": "791001"
        },
        "position": {
            "lat": 28.22394,
            "lng": 94.85208
        },
        "distance": 0,
        "mapView": {
            "west": 94.72013,
            "south": 28.17345,
            "east": 94.9472,
            "north": 28.29374
        }
    }
]
```

}